# Select column showing expand/collapse buttons in jface TreeViewer

Tags: java, jface, treeviewer

I am searching if it is possible to select which of the columns of a org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.TreeViewer shows the expand/collapse buttons.

I have a setup with with 3 TreeViewerColumns, where the first column is fixed width and only shows an icon representing the state for that row.

Therefore I would like the second column to do the expand/collapse functionality.

Is this possible somehow?

I googled, checked examples, etc. but was not able to find anything in this area.